# dig -x +short to file without STDERR

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, stderr, dig

When I do:
dig -x  +short
I get only the hosts output,
but when doing `dig -x <ip> +short > file.txt` I get all the rubbish, as if it was not executed with +short.

I have tried:

```
dig -x <ip> +short 2>&1 > file.txt
```

also

```
dig -x <ip> +short 2>/dev/null > file.txt
```

But didn't work, Thank you

Comment: Use: `dig +short -x <ip>`

Comment: awesome, thank you very much

Comment: ...reposted that comment as a community-wiki answer so the question can be marked solved (without getting undue credit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@anubhava observed in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42856211/dig-x-short-to-file-without-stderr#comment72818557_42856211), ordering matters:

```
dig +short -x "$ip"
```